# MySql Table Reference & Nested Parentheses

Tags: mysql, join, nested

I'd like to ask for some help with the following query.

My goal is to create a list of valid calendar dates (the "make_calendar" section) which are within a specified cut-off month (the "selection_criteria" section).

The "make_calendar" section works great, but when I try to join it to the "selection_criteria", an error occurs: **Unknown column 'selection_criteria.cutoff_date' in 'field list'**

I assume this is because of the nesting (?) but am unsure. Is there a way to reformat this query such that the "make_calendar" section has visibility to the "selection_criteria" section ?

Thank you for any help.

```
select calendar_date

  from ( select ('2018-07-31') cutoff_date ) selection_criteria

       inner join ( select calendar_date
                      from ( select makedate( year( selection_criteria.cutoff_date ),1) + interval (month( selection_criteria.cutoff_date )-1) month + interval daynum day calendar_date
                              from (   select t * 10 + u daynum
                                         from ( select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3) tens,

                                              ( select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
                                                union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7
                                                union select 8 union select 9) singles

                                     order by daynum ) integer_list
                                   ) date_list
                     where month(calendar_date) = month( now() )   
                  ) make_calendar;
```

Comment: It might help to show us, by way of sample data, what you are trying to do.  I don't think I have ever needed to nest a query so many times in real life.

Comment: My use-case is a derivation of the posting found here, which generates a list of calendar dates in the current month:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month

My needs are different because I'm not necessarily seeking dates for the CURRENT month, but instead the dates in ANY given month as identified by the end-of-month cutoff date.

In summary, I am trying to join the logic of the referenced post with on additional SELECT statement which identifies the desired cut-off date.